# Change a Path's Fill color depending on a bool property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `DataTemplate` with a `Path` in a ResourceDictionary and I want to change the `Fill` color for the `Path` (would choose between two colors) depending on a bool property from the viewmodel.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileIcon">
    <Path Data="M20.8573547,8.0085467..." Fill="#F0F1F3" Width="30" Height="30"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I presume, I need to use some converter but not sure how to write the XAML code for it. Something like this?

```
<Path Fill="{Binding MyBoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Path}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Path isn't an ancestor of itself. If the viewmodel is the Path's DataContext, a conventional binding should suffice:

```
<Path 
    Fill="{Binding MyBoolProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorHiddenConverter}}"
    />
```

You could also skip the converter and use a Style trigger. Note that the default Fill is no longer set as an attribute in this version; if it is, then [it'll override anything the Style does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

```
<Path
    Data="M20.8573547,8.0085467..." 
    Width="30" 
    Height="30"
    >
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#F0F1F3" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding MyBoolProperty}"
                    Value="True"
                    >
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="FluorescentBeige" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a converter, you can follow this example code for making one:

**1.** Make a new class

**2.** Use the following namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
```

**3.** Inherit and implement the `IValueConverter` Interface

**4.** In the `Convert` function, evaluate the `value` parameter and return the corresponding color you want

**Example Code**

```
class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
        {
            // return the color you want
        }
        else
        {
            // return the color you want
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```